# Any Social Network engine/gem for Rails 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking for a gem to provide basic social network functionalities, which are:

- User Authentication
- Profile Management
- Private messaging
- In the future, a mini-blog maybe but not essential

I have been looking into currently active projects like `Community Engine` and `Social Stream`. I like Social Stream in particular as you can choose the component you want. However, none of these gems are support RoR 4.0+

Is there any other solutions I can consider? Or else, is there any gem which are like `devise` + something else for messaging? I like devise so I don't mind adding messaging function via another gem. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use devise for authentication and [mailboxer gem](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer) for implementing messaging feature which is a part of social_stream project. This gem is compatible with rails 4+ . You don't actually need a gem for profile management. Also take a look at [faye gem](http://faye.jcoglan.com/security.html) which you can use to publish and subscribe to real-time events. First use mailboxer to implement core messaging system and then use faye to make it realtime.

Comment: A very comprehensive answer! Thank you @deep!

Answer (score 5):

There are actually quite a few :

[Social Stream](https://github.com/ging/social_stream) : A complete social network that includes everything you would want from a social network.

[Diaspora](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora) : Same features as social stream, more active.

Here's a complete [list](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=social+network)

Or, you can quickly create your own with the following gems:

1) [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) : User authentication 
2) [Mailboxer](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer): Messaging
3) [Activity Stream](https://github.com/evilmarty/activity_stream) : public/private activities
4) [Socialization](https://github.com/cmer/socialization) : Friendship model

Comment: Thanks @rb512. The problem is that Social Stream and Diaspora are not compatible with Rails 4.0 at the moment. Basically it seems like none of them support 4.0.

Comment: unless there has been an update in the last day or two which I haven't seen, Social Stream does not work with rails 4.0

Comment: It's the implementation of the server for the distributed social network diaspora*. It is not a reusable library or framework to build your own social network

Answer (score 1):

Community Engine currently supports Rails 4+ and has branches for rails 3 and 2. It should meet all of your requirements.

You can find it here:

https://github.com/bborn/communityengine

and

http://communityengine.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something for organizations like **facebook for work/yammer** you can checkout one little open source project I did :- https://github.com/sahilbathlaofficial/soapbox

It is very basic and has minimal features :-

Followers, Groups, messaging, twitter integration